# How To Delete Child Records From Table That Not Have Parent

Tags: sql

How to delete child records from table tradecode that not have parent on tradecode ?

parent and child exist on table trade code based on table MappingCodeValue parent and child

so i need to delete records from trade code table that not have parent on table trade code

so according to my explain two rows 5,6 on trade code table will be deleted

```
TradeCodeId  PartId CodeType   CodeValue    
5        1444   ECCS-URB    AB666-URB             
6        1931   ECCS-URB    AB778-URB
```

5 and 6 is child and not have parent rows as AB666-US and AB778-US

so it wrong and i will delete it

but another rows on trade code have parent and child according to table mappingcodevalue so that it is correct

so how to write query delete rows that have rows that have child and not have parent from trade code

based on value exist on mappingcodevalue

```
drop table #MappingCodeValue
drop table #TradeCode
create table #MappingCodeValue
 (
 id int identity (1,1),
 ParentCodeType  nvarchar(50),
 ParentCodeValue  nvarchar(50),
 ChildCodeType  nvarchar(50),
 ChildCodeValue  nvarchar(50)
 )
 INSERT INTO #MappingCodeValue
 (ParentCodeType,ParentCodeValue,ChildCodeType,ChildCodeValue)
 VALUES
 ('ECCS-US','AB123-US','ECCS-URB','AB123-URB'),
 ('ECCS-US','AB555-US','ECCS-URB','AB555-URB'),
 ('ECCS-US','AB666-US','ECCS-URB','AB666-URB'),
 ('ECCS-US','AB756-US','ECCS-URB','AB756-URB')


 CREATE TABLE #TradeCode
 (
 TradeCodeId int identity(1,1),
 PartId  int,
 CodeType  nvarchar(50),
 CodeValue nvarchar(50)
 )
 insert into #TradeCode(PartId,CodeType,CodeValue)VALUES
 (1222,'ECCS-US','AB123-US'),
 (1255,'ECCS-US','AB555-US'),
 (1222,'ECCS-URB','AB123-URB'),
 (1255,'ECCS-URB','AB555-URB'),
 (1444,'ECCS-URB','AB666-URB'),
 (1931,'ECCS-URB','AB778-URB')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 'NOT IN'.

As in

```
SELECT *
from childtable
where parentid not in (select id  from parenttable)
```